# Use python -m json.tool to output Chinese UTF-8

Tags: python, json, cjk

Original text file "chinese.txt" like following

`{"type":"FeatureCollection","text":"你好"}`

on Mac run command in Terminal like following

`$ cat chinese.txt | python -m json.tool`

The output is

```
{
    "text": "\u4f60\u597d",
    "type": "FeatureCollection"
}
```

How add parameter to avoid the "\u4f60\u597d" and get "你好"

What I like to do is the use `python -m json.tool` from the shell without modifying the code of `json.tool`.  A common use case is to reformat a UTF-8 encoded json file, and keep the Chinese characters not like the \uxxxx.

Comment: I'm not sure I see the point of the whole command in that case?

Comment: Or use [jq](https://stedolan.github.io/jq/download/)

Comment: we can use option `python -m json.tool --no-ensure-ascii`, tested on python 3.9.9

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As of Python 3.9, `json.tool` has a new `--no-ensure-ascii` [option](https://docs.python.org/3/library/json.html#cmdoption-json.tool-no-ensure-ascii) for this.

Before 3.9, you'll need to use something else. This is (most of) the source for [the 3.8 version](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/3.8/Lib/json/tool.py) of `json.tool`:

```
prog = 'python -m json.tool'
description = ('A simple command line interface for json module '
               'to validate and pretty-print JSON objects.')
parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(prog=prog, description=description)
parser.add_argument('infile', nargs='?',
                    type=argparse.FileType(encoding="utf-8"),
                    help='a JSON file to be validated or pretty-printed',
                    default=sys.stdin)
parser.add_argument('outfile', nargs='?',
                    type=argparse.FileType('w', encoding="utf-8"),
                    help='write the output of infile to outfile',
                    default=sys.stdout)
parser.add_argument('--sort-keys', action='store_true', default=False,
                    help='sort the output of dictionaries alphabetically by key')
parser.add_argument('--json-lines', action='store_true', default=False,
                    help='parse input using the jsonlines format')
options = parser.parse_args()

infile = options.infile
outfile = options.outfile
sort_keys = options.sort_keys
json_lines = options.json_lines
with infile, outfile:
    try:
        if json_lines:
            objs = (json.loads(line) for line in infile)
        else:
            objs = (json.load(infile), )
        for obj in objs:
            json.dump(obj, outfile, sort_keys=sort_keys, indent=4)
            outfile.write('\n')
    except ValueError as e:
        raise SystemExit(e)
```

The problem is you have no way to add parameters to the call to `json.dump` - you'd want to do this instead:

```
json.dump(obj, outfile, sort_keys=sort_keys, indent=4, ensure_ascii=False)
```

But you'll have to write your own script for that, `json.tool` won't help you here.